# 2Column CSS Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following:

```
<div id="aboutus">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="headerbar"><p>ABOUT US</p></div>
<div id="contentarea">
<p>CONTENT ABOUT US</div>
<div id="clear"></div></div>

<div id="contact">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="headerbar"><p>CONTACT US</p></div></div>
<div id="contentarea">CONTENT CONTACT US</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and:

```css
#aboutus {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#contact{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#headerbar {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#contentarea{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    height:100px;
}
#clear{
    clear: both;
}
#header{
    background:url(bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:contain;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

I'm totally new to  this so I'm sure I'm doing something silly. Basically its two 2 collumn layouts on top of one another, the aboutus div is fine however the contact div displays within the about us div. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to specify two divs on top of another, can specify `display:block;` with the `width:100%;` like below

```
.div{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You don't have to use floats. Of course, there's a plenty of ways you can achieve, this is one of the way to do that. You can play around about this here http://jsfiddle.net/qiqiabaziz/mrrQU/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<div id="aboutus">
<div class="header"><div class="headerbar"><p>ABOUT US</p></div></div>
<div class="contentarea">
<p>CONTENT ABOUT US</div>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<div id="contact">
<div class="header"><div class="headerbar"><p>CONTACT US</p></div></div>
<div class="contentarea">CONTENT CONTACT US</div></div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And:

```
#aboutus {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#contact{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#headerbar {
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5px;
}
.contentarea{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    height:100px;
}
#clear{
    clear: both;
}
.header{
    width:25%;
    height:100px;    
    background:url(bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:contain;
    float: left;
}
div {border:1px black solid;
}
```

I added borders so you can see where your divs are. Floats are aways tricky to deal with, and more complicated when you use it 100% of your screen.

Tip: use ID for unique objects on your code, and CLASS for elements that repeat on the same page (#id is for single elements, .class is for when you want to apply the same style to more than one element on your page).

Play here: http://jsfiddle.net/VPzyy/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you run your html through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (it's a good practice), you'll see that you have an extra `</div>` tag in there. If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, it's one of the two after your second headerbar div. That extra `</div>` tag is closing your contact div when you don't want it to close yet.

I personally always leave a comment when I'm closing a div so that I can see exactly what `</div>` is closing what. Like this:

```
<div id = "outerdiv">
     <div class = "innerdiv">
          <p>text</p>
          <div class = "innerdiv2">
               <p>more text</p>
          </div><!-- .innerdiv2 -->
     </div><!-- .innerdiv -->
</div><!-- #outerdiv-->
```

This way, even if I mess up the indentation, it's still easy to see exactly what's going on.